# Storage external or internal

Tags: android, storage

I am new in this issue, I read a lot of topics on stackoverflow and I'm in a muddle now. I have one simple question, if I create file in my application package, I call getExternalCacheDir(), it means that I save this file on SDcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I call getExternalCacheDir(), it means that I save this file on SDcard?

No, that puts it on external storage. [External storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), in general.

On Android 4.4+, `getExternalCacheDirs()` (note the plural method name) *may* return locations on removable storage that you can write to.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I'm grateful. I have one extra question, so, if I would like to save something on SDcard, which command should I call?

Comment: @pupilx: You *may* be able to access removable media on Android 4.4+ using `getExternalCacheDirs()`, as noted in my answer.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. And before Android 4.4+? I read a lot of getExternalStorageDirectory(), is something diffrent else?

Comment: @pupilx: Removable storage is not supported in the Android SDK prior to Android 4.4. I cover this in the blog posts that I linked to in my answer -- please read them.